# Using scene builder to make a program

Tags: java

I have been given an assignment using a program I coded earlier in my course and I need to convert the code graphically. Now I am trying to use the code below to convert the program to a graphical version via the Scene Builder using Net Beans. I am not entirely sure how to use code to make a graphical program.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TemperatureConversion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
        char convertFrom = 'C';
        double celsius = 0, fahrenheit = 0, celsius_result = 0, temprature_result = 0;

        do {
            System.out.println("Convert from degree C, enter C; Convert from degree F, enter F: ");
            convertFrom = Character.toUpperCase(scnr.next().charAt(0));
        } while (!((convertFrom == 'C') || (convertFrom == 'F')));

        System.out.println("Enter degree in " + convertFrom + ": ");

        switch (convertFrom) {
            case 'C':
                //System.out.println("Enter The Temperature in Celsius:");
                celsius = scnr.nextDouble();
                temprature_result = CelsiusToFahrenheit(celsius);
                System.out.println(celsius + "C equals " + temprature_result + "F");
                break;
            case 'F':
                //System.out.println("Enter The Temperature in fahrenheit:");
                fahrenheit = scnr.nextDouble();
                celsius_result = FahrenheitToCelsius(fahrenheit);
                System.out.println(fahrenheit + "F equals " + celsius_result + "C");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Wrong Choice:");
        }
        scnr.close();
    }

    private static double FahrenheitToCelsius(double fahrenheit) {
        double celsius = 0;
        celsius = (fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9;
        return celsius;
    }

    private static double CelsiusToFahrenheit(double celsius) {
        double fahrenheit = 0;
        fahrenheit = celsius * 9 / 5 + 32;
        return fahrenheit;
    }
}
```

Comment: Was there any additional information provided in your course regarding the assignment? There are many possible correct answers, but turning in an answer that uses methods not covered in the class could be interesting if you can't explain how to use them.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you will need to use JavaFX to create a GUI for this. Here is the official documentation and the java docs for JavaFX. Please note this is a simple tutorial. For your program you will need to apply java charts so i suggest you look for that in the docs. Hope this helps!

Java Docs:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/hello_world.htm